# Google Apps/Drive sync with shared storage on local server

Tags: storage, google-drive-api, shared

We are using google apps as a company for almost 2 years now and we are pretty happy with it. with the introduction of Google Drive we are looking in a way to synchronize our network drive with the Google Drive for the complete Google Apps domain. This way we can make it possible for everyone to work from anywhere they like and have access to all the files from every user.

But somehow I can't figure out how this could be possible or even if it's possible. Is there anyone who has maybe done this before or can point me in the right direction?